# Selecting rows and columns - error results

Tags: r, indexing

I have this code in R:

```
Country <- c("USA", "GBR", "CHN")
Gold<-c(46,27,26)
Silver=c(37,23,18)
Bronze=c(38,17,26)

medals <- data.frame(Country, Gold, Silver, Bronze)
```

I wanted select any rows where the number of Gold medals won is 27 or more
which is this line:

```
medals[medals$Gold >= 27,]
```

The question is: at the beginning I forgot to inset the comma at the end so I typed:

```
medals[medals$Gold >= 27]
```

It came up with random results, I would like to know why those results came instead of giving me error? on what basis ? the result even doesn't follow the conidiations.

Answer (score 3):

If you forget the comma, you will select columns instead of rows. If you check your subsetting vector, you'll get this:

```r
medals$Gold >= 27
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

So, when you select your columns with this logical vector, you get the first, second, but not third column. Besides, `[` uses recycling, meaning that the vector is repeated to match the length of the vector (here 4, the number of columns). So the final vector interpreted by `[` is `TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE`.

This is why you get the first, second and fourth columns:

```r
medals[medals$Gold >= 27]

#  Country Gold Bronze
#1     USA   46     38
#2     GBR   27     17
#3     CHN   26     26
```

Comment: Thank you so much, great explanation, just thinking where the condition (>= 27) fits in your answer, so does it compare it with each column? Thanks again in advance.

Comment: No, it does for each row (here you have three); but it is used to select the columns.